Why are GeoTIFF files all white in image viewers?
In any image editor (GIMP, paint.net) or viewer in Windows (Photo Viewer), including using .net framework calls, when opening a GeoTIFF formatted file the image width and height are correct, but there is no data, all pixels are 255 255 255. I understand that the GeoTIFF file strictly follows the TIFF format, but stil their images are not viewable.
Why is this? I can see with a HEX editor that the files are full of data, but no systems seem capable of accessing it.
The file I am using to evaluate this phenomenon is from https://environment.data.gov.uk/survey, specifically tile SP64se. Clearly I can't upload it as for its size, but this is the link for you to access and test independently.



Please provide a test image. How does QGIS show your image? What does gdalinfo your_image.tif -stats report about the datatype and statistics?

I have downloaded QGIS and it can see the elevation data.. Why can nothing else?

Nothing is most probably wrong word. Rather "none of those that you have tried". Maybe your viewer cannot scale higher bit-depth data like DEM. I guess that your DEM is using 32-bit floats. Some common image viewers can, I believe that IrfanView is one of those, and GIMP.

GIMP specifically is not working..

If is elevation data it might only be single band so where does your (255,255,255) triple come from? Is that the colour GIMP is using to represent this? We really need an example...

It is impossible to say if you do not provide test data and tell what software you are using. Check how many bands QGIS sees and what pixel value is shows with the query tool. If the other software shows something different it feels like it is doign something wrong.

I've added a link to the data, with the display in QGIS and GIMP, hopefully this helps.

It's not because it's a geotiff, that's got nothing to do with it.  It's because the data is 32bit single band floating point, not 8bit (greyscale or RGB).  GIS software scales the data to 8bit for viewing.  Simple image viewers can't handle high bit depth images.  More advanced image software like GIMP can but you need to tell the software how.  You can see it in GIMP if you stretch/scale it (e.g. Colors | Auto | Stretch Contrast or similar, I haven't tested much as I don't use GIMP for raw data like this).

@User2856 this is the answer - put it in the answer box instead of a comment - before I do!

I downloaded a random tile "lidar_composite_dtm-2022-1-TM22nw.zip". Do you believe it is from the same dataset? The name of the TIFF file inside the zip is TM22nw_DTM_1m.tif. GIMP does show the gray shades by applying the automatic contrast stretch. The pixel value viewer in GIMP seems to show the value of the rendered image, not the original data value.

It's not because it's a geotiff, it's because the data is 32bit single band floating point, not 8bit (greyscale or RGB). GIS software scales the data to 8bit for viewing. Simple image viewers can't handle high bit depth images. More advanced image software like GIMP can but you need to tell the software how. You can see it in GIMP if you stretch/scale it (e.g. Colors | Auto | Stretch Contrast or similar).
Here is SP64se (2m) in GIMP:


Wow, I've never seen GIMP do that, thanks! Is that GIMP working in 32bpp greyscale?

I just opened the tiff in GIMP and as you showed, it displays as all white by default so I applied a basic contrast stretch to get that output.
